# How to override country drop-down in checkout page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, country-regions

I want to override country drop-down in custom checkout page. In further i want to add my custom function on change of country drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Provide information to get help: what custom checkout is? is there custom theme installed and used? What other module are enabled?

It work in default by changing `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` in theme/module and additional js file need to be added as ui_component.

Comment: I am working in my custom module for checkout. In my custom module i want to update shipping method on change event of country drop-down changed. So from where in default magento shipping method updated on change of country drop-down. So i can over write that file in my module.